# Air application running only in builder environment

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have an air application that loads a swf ( built in flex ) , this swf loads moduls and basicaly my air application is a testing environment for this swf .

when i run it in flex environment ( eclipse ) it runs fine , when i run it from my programs ( as an air program ) it gets stuck , what i was thinking is that it has to do with security issues because it gets stuck when my main swf try to loads the moduls .
is the air sandbox security different then flex ?

Thanks

Comment: where are you loading swf's from? local machine or remote server? Are the paths correct?

Comment: from my local machine , the paths are correct.  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When an application is installed, all
>   files included within an AIR installer
>   file are installed onto the user's
>   computer into an application
>   directory. All files within the
>   application directory tree are
>   assigned to the application sandbox
>   when the application is run. Content
>   in the application sandbox is allowed
>   the full privileges available to an
>   AIR application, including interaction
>   with the local file system.
>
> Many AIR applications use only these
>   locally installed files to run the
>   application. However, AIR applications
>   are not restricted to just the files
>   within the application directory —
>   they can load any type of file from
>   any source. This includes files on the
>   user's computer as well as files from
>   external sources, such as those on a
>   local network or from the Internet.
>   File type has no impact on security
>   restrictions; loaded HTML files have
>   the same security privileges as loaded
>   SWF files from the same source.
>   (However, content in the application
>   sandbox is restricted from loading
>   JavaScript files from outside that
>   sandbox. Details are provided in the
>   developer documentation.)
>
> Content in the application security
>   sandbox has access to AIR APIs that
>   content in other sandboxes is
>   prevented from using. For example,
>   only content in the application
>   security sandbox can read and write to
>   the local file system.
>
> Some JavaScript techniques exist for
>   dynamically transforming strings into
>   executable code. Content in the
>   application security sandbox can only
>   use these techniques while code is
>   loading from application URLs. Using
>   these techniques within the
>   application sandbox would pose a
>   security risk. For example, an
>   application could inadvertently
>   execute a string loaded from a network
>   sandbox, and that string may contain
>   malicious code, such as code to delete
>   or alter files on the user’s computer
>   or to report back the contents of a
>   local file to an untrusted network
>   domain. Details are provided in the
>   developer documentation.

If the SWF is not in the Air applications sandbox (ie the Application folder) than it cannot cross-script with the AIR file. [Here is the detailed description](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/air_security/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11c0f598475-7ff9.html).